# Update existing database using entityframework

Tags: identityserver4

We are upgrading our installation of IdentityServer4 from 2.1.1 to 2.5.4 but are unsure on the best approach to update the existing database.

We have updated the nuget packages from 2.1.1 to 2.5.4 
- IdentityServer4.EntityFramework
- IdentityServer4.AsNetIdentity

We tried to add-migrations and generate the sql scripts
dotnet ef migrations script -c configurationdbcontext -i -o confcontxt.sql

But it appears that the model changes does not result in the necessary sql (AlterTable ....)

What are we missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Strange but apparently deleting the _EFMigrationsHistory did the trick. Read [EF migration shows empty Up() Down() methods, no tables created in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359799/ef-migration-shows-empty-up-down-methods-no-tables-created-in-database) or/and 
[EF migration shows empty Up() Down() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708519/ef-migration-shows-empty-up-down-methods/50087619#50087619)

All the basic EntityFramework stuff is well documented here: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations